# Magento 2 - How to add new action type in shopping cart rule

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want to add New action type Name = **Buy 1 get 1**.

If anyone gets 1 product and cart rule condition true then I give one free product to that order.

How to add the new action to cart rule. and how to calculate that cart rule.

Does have any solution for this?

Comment: Did you check? http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-buy-x-get-y-free.html

Comment: @Keyur Shah ......I already see that ...But I need to add new action type in cart rule........

Comment: @Keyur Shah ...How to find out which files are calculate these process